# Let $R$ be a ring that has no nonzero nilpotent commutators. If $e\in R$ is an idempotent, then $e\in Z(R)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring that has no nonzero nilpotent commutators. If $e\in R$ is an idempotent, then $e\in Z(R)$.

I have a problem with proving this theorem. I don't know how to understand nonzero nilpotent commutators.

Comment: Commutators are elements of the form $ab-ba$. Nilpotent means an element $a$ such that $a^n=0$ for some $n$.

Comment: I know the definitions of commutator and nilpotent. Hovewer, I wonder what means nilpotent commutators. Is this $\bigl[x,\, y\bigr]^{n}=0$?

Comment: @Monika Yes, that is the most apparent meaning. "Nonzero" and "nilpotent" are adjectives, and "commutator" is a noun, and in English, when you put adjectives in front of the noun, the noun accumulates those adjectives.

Answer (score 6):

This appears to be a misstatement of the following theorem:

> If $R$ is a ring with **no** nonzero nilpotent commutators, then all idempotents are central.

The reason is that if $e$ is idempotent, then $[e,er]^2=0$ and $[e,re]^2=0$. The condition that commutators which are nilpotent are zero forces $[e,er]=[e,re]=0$, and if you expand them this says that $er=ere=re$, showing that $e$ is central.

---

**Edit**: The OP was consequently edited to have the correctly stated problem.

Answer (score 2):

Let $e$ be an idempotent and $x$ be any element of the ring. Calculation shows that $[e,ex]^2 = 0$. But you have no non-zero nilpotent commutator. This meanns that you must have $[e,ex] =0$ which implies that $ex = exe$. In a similar way you must have $[e,xe] = 0$ which means that $xe = exe$. comparing with previous $ex = exe$ we get $ex=xe$. Thus $e \in Z(R)$.

Answer (score 2):

**Theorem**: Let $R$ be a ring that has no nonzero nilpotent commutators. If $e ∈ R$ is an idempotent, then $e ∈ Z(R)$.

*Proof*: Let $e^2=e$ be an idempotent, and $y\in R$.  Then $(ey−eye)^2 =0=(ye−eye)^2$ for all $y ∈ R$. Just expand and compute. But $ey-eye=eey-eye=[e,ey]$ is a commutator, as well as $ye − eye = [ye,e]$.
Since there are no nilpotent commutators except for zero, we must have
$ey−eye=ye−eye=0$ for all $y∈R$. Thus $ey=ye$ and $e∈Z(R)$.

Answer (score 1):

You made a mistake. The right assertion sounds as follows:

Let $R$ be a ring that has no nonzero nilpotent commutators. If $e \in R$
is an idempotent, then $e \in Z(R)$.

This is Theorem 8 from

http://archive.maths.nuim.ie/staff/sbuckley/Papers/bm_variations.pdf

Answer (score 0):

An easier proof: 
Let $e^2=e\in R$ and $x\in R$. Therefore, $x=xe+x(1-e)$. Hence, $ex-exe=ex(1-e)$. Squaring gives $(ex-exe)^2=ex(1-e)ex(1-e)=0$. Since $R$ has no nonzero nilpotent elements, $ex=exe$. On the other hand, $(xe-exe)^2=0$. Again, by the hypothesis that $R$ has no nonzero nilpotent elements, $xe=exe$. Thus, $ex=xe$, i.e., $e\in Z(R)$.