# Prove $R$ has no nonzero nilpotent elements iff $x^2=0$ implies $x=0$. Then show idempotents are central in such a ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Prove that the following statements for a ring $R$ are equivalent:
>
> (a) $R$ has no nonzero nilpotent elements.
>
> (b) If $a\in R$ such that $a^2=0$, then $a=0$.
>
> Furthermore, show that under any of the conditions (a) or (b) all idempotents are central.

For part $(a) \Rightarrow (b)$ is trivial, where I mess it is in part $(b)\Rightarrow (a)$, could someone help me? Which means that all idempotents are central?

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1478754/does-reduceness-of-kt-1-dots-t-n-i-imply-radicality-of-i/1478827#1478827)

Comment: @André3000 This was better/more helpful than the chosen answer. You should have pasted this as an answer, I think.

Comment: @TheLedge I'm glad you found my answer at the link helpful. If anything, I would have voted to close this as a duplicate of the linked question. But that didn't seem quite right since the question in that post is a special case of this one, even though my answer is general. Anyway, this question got closed and now has 1 delete vote, so it may not be visible for much longer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose $x^n=0$ with $n>1$. We can always find $1\le m<n$ such that $x^m=0$. By induction, this shows that $x=0$.

If $n$ is even, this follows from the hypotheses in (b).

If $n$ is odd, then $x^{n+1}=0$, so $x^{\frac{n+1}{2}}=0$ with $\frac{n+1}{2}<n$ as $1<n$.

Also, we say an idempotent is central if it is in the center of $R$, i.e. if it commutes with all elements in the ring. The implication that any of these equivalent conditions implies all idempotents are central can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/454811/let-r-be-a-ring-that-has-no-nonzero-nilpotent-commutators-if-e-in-r-is-an-i).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty easy proof. Boils down to showing that $a \in R \text{ and } a^n=0 \implies a=0$ for any integer $n$. HINT: use associativity of multiplication.

Comment: $a^n=0$, so $(a)(a)(a)(a)...(a)(a)(a)(a)=0$, $(aa)(aa)(aa)...(aa)=0$ If n is even, $(a^2)(a^2)...(a^2)=0$, $a=0$.
If n is odd: $(a^2)(a^2)...(a)=0$ so $a=0$ ? that's fine?

Comment: Well as the last answer indicated it's an inductive argument and the inductive hypothesis is used when $n$ is odd, since $a^{n+1}=a^{n-1}a^2$.