# A ring $R$ has no nonzero nilpotent elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Prove that a ring $R$ has no nonzero nilpotent elements if and only if for any $a\in R$, $a^2=0 \implies a=0$.

$"\Rightarrow"$ Assume that $R$ is ring has no nonzero nilpotent elements. Suppose $a^2=0$. If $a\neq 0$, then $a$ is a nilpotent elements of $R$, so $R$ has a nonzero nilpotent, which contradict the assumption. Hence, $a$ must be zero.

$"\Leftarrow"$ Assume that for any $a \in R$, if $a^2=0$ then $a=0.$ Let $a \in R$. Let us assume for the contrary that there is $0 \neq a \in R$ such that $a^n=0$. We will distinguish two cases:

(i) $n=2k+1$, so $a^n=(a^k)^2(a)=0$ which implies that $(a^k)^2=0$ so by assumption $a^k=0$.

(ii) $n=2k$, so we must have $a^k=0$.

I can not see why $a$ must be zero here.

I would appreciate any thoughts or other suggestion ways to prove that.
Thank you.

Comment: Why does $a^{2k}a = 0$ imply $a^{2k}=0$? Is it true in a ring that $ab=0$ implies $a=0$ or $b=0$?

Comment: Have you compared with the proofs at the [duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2002138/prove-r-has-no-nonzero-nilpotent-elements-iff-x2-0-implies-x-0-then-show)?

Comment: No, 2.2=0 in $Z_4$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a quick and simple way to prove this, which does not depend on even/odd cases etc., or any of the (iteratively) linked citings, but is indeed quite concise and self contained:

As pointed out by our OP Ahmed in the text of the question itself, the "$\Rightarrow$" direction is virtually self-evident, that is, if $R$ has no non-zero nilpotents and $a^2 = 0$, then clearly $a = 0$ as well.

As for the "$\Leftarrow$" direction, we observe that

$a^2 = 0 \Longrightarrow a = 0 \tag 1$

implies, for any $x \in R$ and $m \ge 1$,

$x^{2^m} = 0 \Longrightarrow x^{2^{m - 1}} = 0, \tag 2$

since

$(x^{2^{m - 1}})^2 = x^{2^{m - 1}}x^{2^{m - 1}} = x^{2^{m - 1}+2^{m - 1}} = x^{2^1 2^{m - 1}} = x^{2^m} = 0. \tag 3$

In light of (2), we may evidently proceed downward, one decrement of $m$ at a time, until we eventually reach $m = 1$, *viz*:

$x^{2^m} = 0 \Longrightarrow x^{2^{m - 1}} = 0 \Longrightarrow x^{2^{m - 2}} = 0$
$\Longrightarrow \ldots \Longrightarrow x^2 = 0 \Longrightarrow x = 0. \tag 4$

Now if $b \in R$ is nilpotent,

$b^n = 0, \tag 5$

we simply choose $m$ sufficiently large that

$2^m \ge n; \tag 6$

then

$b^{2^m} = b^{2^m - n}b^n = 0; \tag 7$

at this point (2)-(4) take over and we conclude that

$b = 0; \tag 8$

$R$ has no non-zere nilpotent elements.  $OE\Delta$.

Answer (score 2):

In the proof it has been shown that if $a^{2k}=0$ or $a^{2k+1}=0$ then $a^{k}=0$.

Therefore whatever power of $a$ is zero you can find a smaller power which is zero until you get $a=0$.

Comment: What reason you use to say that " whatever power of  is zero you can find a smaller power which is zero until you get $=0$." I can not see your reason.

Comment: For example:- Suppose that $a^7=0$. Then in the proof it is shown that $a^3=0$. Since $a^3=0$ the proof then shows that $a^1=0$.

Comment: I got you... Thanks alot..